# How to resolve Webpack server error in React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to resolve this error but I dont know what to do. I have intalled the Babel extension then started gettin this error and then I deleted that. However, I am getting error now also so maybe it has nothing to do with it. Please help me figuring out.

[Error: ]

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:#4 Web Development\\React-Concepts\\learn-react-
2\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\client\\index.js?
protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22wa
rnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'D:#4 Web Development\\React-
Concepts\\learn-react-2'
ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:#4 Web Development\\React-Concepts\\learn-react-
2\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\client\\index.js?
protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22wa
rnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&live-reload=true' in 'D:#4 Web Development\\React-
Concepts\\learn-react-2'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "learn-react-2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use a module that you have not installed, as I can see from the error I would suggest you to try this:

npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev

Solution:
Remove '#' from the directory "#4 Web Development"

Comment: Tried this, still not working

Comment: Try removing the # from "#4 Web Development"

Comment: hats off man ! Thanks a lot !! I dont know how did you find that out. Can you please tell me so that I can find these errors on my own. Anyways Thanks a ton !

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked, did some research on the web that's how I found out.